Variance estimation from dependent data
I would like to estimate the variance of a zero-mean normal distribution, $x_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, from data of the form $y_n = u_n x_n$ where the input $u_n \in [u_{\min}, u_{\max}]$ can be actively chosen in each iteration $n$, i.e. $u_n$ is not fixed a prior but highly dependent on previous choices.
How could the variance $\sigma^2$ be estimated in this scenario?
EDIT: Some more details/additional assumptions

We can assume $0 < u_{\min} < u_{\max}$.
Dependence on previous choices: I am interested in estimating $\sigma^2$ from a time series $(u_0, y_0)$, $(u_1, y_1)$, ... The values of $u_n$ however are not independent, but chosen according to some decision criterion which can depend on the previous estimate of $\sigma^2$
I am looking for an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$


In order to develop an answer, it would be helpful to know (1) how $u_n$ is "dependent on previous choices;" (2) what the possible values of $u_{min}$ and $u_{max}$ could be; and (3) what kind of estimator you are looking for (there are many ranging from unbiased linear to minimax to MLE and so on).  Could you let us know?
